# Exam class - customising question numbers

Tags: exam

I am writing a document in exam class. The exam has several sections. I would like the question numbers in the second section to continue on from the first section.

The code below produces Question 1 and Question 2 in both sections. I would like to have Question 1, Question 2 in Section 1 and Question 3, Question 4 in Section 2. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
Section 1.
\question ...

\question ...
\end{questions}

Section 2.
\begin{questions}
\question ...

\question ...
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How do you denote sections? Just by writing `Section 1` or by using some command?

Comment: @TeXnician Just by writing Section 1